# How to save the same ID on two different user's branch with Firebase, C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a game where after a queue players will fight against each other.
I add a unique ID for their match with push function.

However, since they both call this push function, it will generate two different IDs.

How could I generate one common ID and then save that to both player's branch?

(My rules don't allow for a user to modify an other user's data, in this example their active match's ID)

I have the following code:

```
string matchUID = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("rooms").Child(currentRoom).Child("matches").Push().Key; 

FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("rooms").Child(currentRoom).Child("queue").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).RemoveValueAsync();
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("currentMatch").SetValueAsync(matchUID);
if (smallestKey == auth.CurrentUser.UserId) {
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("rooms").Child(currentRoom).Child("matches").Child(matchUID).Child(smallestKey).SetValueAsync("Loaded");
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("rooms").Child(currentRoom).Child("matches").Child(matchUID).Child(secondSmallestKey).SetValueAsync("Loaded");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but each time you call `Push()` it will generate a location with a unique key. So if you get two different keys, you're calling `Push()` twice.

Comment: I realized the problem and I updated the question's description.

Comment: The API doesn't provide a function that lets two arbitrary apps to share a randomly generated value.  You would have to do something special to figure out how to share that data between the clients so they can both use it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still not sure I understand, but: if you want both users to store the same push ID, you need generte the `matchUID` [sic] once, and then pass that to both users.

Comment: Yes, now my question is about how or where can I generate it only once? I am using Unity game engine and basically every client/user calls that code so it will generate a different UID every time.

Comment: In that case you'll have to find a way to share the game ID between the users, as Doug also commented. Firebase has nothing built in for that, but a common way is to: 1) sign the users in to the app, 2) allow them to connect to friends (by name, or email address are most common), 3) then they can share withint the database, as they'll know each other's User ID.